# Determining a the value of an infinite sum from geometric progression and series

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

**Question:**

Let $\Bbb N=\{0,1,2,3,...\}$

Given that $$\sum_{i,j\in \Bbb N}\frac{1}{a^ib^j}=\left(\sum_{i\in N}\frac{1}{a^i}\right)\left(\sum_{j\in N}\frac{1}{b^j}\right)$$

where $gcd(a,b)=1$ and $a,b\in \Bbb N^+$, find the value of the infinite sum
$$\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{15}+\frac{1}{16}+...=
\sum_{i,j,k\in \Bbb N}\frac{1}{2^i3^j5^k}$$.

**My attempt:**

I get it that $$\sum_{i,j\in \Bbb N}\frac{1}{a^ib^j}=\frac{1}{a^0b^0}+\frac{1}{a^0b^0}+\frac{1}{a^0b^1}+\frac{1}{a^0b^2}+\frac{1}{a^0b^3}+
\frac{1}{a^1b^0}+\frac{1}{a^1b^1}+\frac{1}{a^1b^2}+\frac{1}{a^1b^3}+
\frac{1}{a^2b^0}+\frac{1}{a^2b^1}+\frac{1}{a^2b^2}+\frac{1}{a^2b^3}+
\frac{1}{a^3b^0}+...$$

and rearranging gives
$$\begin{aligned}\sum_{i,j\in \Bbb N}\frac{1}{a^ib^j}&=1+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{1}{b^3}+
1+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{a^3}+
\frac{1}{ab}+\frac{1}{ab^2}+\frac{1}{ab^3}+\frac{1}{a^2b}+\frac{1}{a^2b^2}+\frac{1}{a^2b^3}+...\\
\left(\sum_{i\in \Bbb N}\frac{1}{a^i}\right)\left(\sum_{j\in \Bbb N}\frac{1}{b^j}\right)&=\left(1+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{1}{b^3}+...\right)
\left(1+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{a^3}+...\right)\end{aligned}$$

From here, I thought that

$$\begin{aligned}\sum_{i,j,k\in \Bbb N}\frac{1}{2^i3^j5^k}&=\left(\sum_{i\in \Bbb N}\frac{1}{2^i}\right)\left(\sum_{j\in \Bbb N}\frac{1}{3^j}\right)\left(\sum_{k\in \Bbb N}\frac{1}{5^k}\right)\\&=\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+...\right)
\left(1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{3^3}+...\right)
\left(1+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{5^2}+\frac{1}{5^3}+...\right)
\end{aligned}$$

However, I do not know how to proceed from here.

(1) How do I solve the individual series in each parenthesis?

(2) Neither do I know that how does $gcd(a,b)=1$ is critical to this question.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know how to sum a geometric series?

Comment: Each sum is a simple geometric series.  $\sum x^k=\frac{1}{1-x}$ for $x\lt 1$.

Comment: I too do not see why $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ is relevant.